# Is "eachother" correct?

Tags: word-choice

I recently saw someone intentionally use "[eachother](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/6918/revisions)" instead of "each other".  In what circumstances would this be correct?

Comment: It does appear that in the case you cite, the change to *eachother* was done by a foreigner (listed location: Netherlands, age 15). In Dutch, *each other* is the single word *elkaar*.

Comment: To me, it sounds about as correct as `foreach` or `goto`.

Comment: @nohat - That would be me, and while I do speak English natively, I like anyone still make mistakes. I stand corrected. (In my defence, I have seen it used by a native speaker, which is where I picked it up anyway)

Comment: @dbkk: There are also languages with control statements like `ifelse`; that doesn't mean that _ifelse_ sounds correct, in English.

Comment: @Arda Xi, I don’t mean to judge you negatively; I just presented a theory that I thought might explain the error. I guess my theory was wrong.

Comment: @dbkk But *foreach* **is** correct. That's what my compiler tells me! (I joking, of course.) What language uses *ifelse*, by the way? I know of *else if* only...

Comment: I was born in England and have lived here all my life. At school, I was taught to always use "eachother". I found this site because my spellchecker complained about this word.

Comment: @LeeBoy Although there is only one stress in *each other*, we still write it as two words. It is not acceptable in any version of written English to spell those two words without an intervening space between them.

Comment: I think it one compelling reason for spelling it as a single word, even if currently incorrect, is that it is pronounced differently than the two separate words: people say something like "ea-Chother" -- I think the emphasis changes. There are certainly other examples of two words which have become consolidated into one that are not more compelling -- why is "myself" not two separate words?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my view this is not a valid alternate for "each other" under any circumstances. I would go as far as saying it's plain incorrect.

Saying that, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eachother) lists it as a "non-standard spelling", though that's an understatement. Neither the OED nor Webster's lists it at all. I have certainly never seen it used by any native speaker of English in my life.

Comment: I always try to spell it as "eachother." The only reason I don't is because of the red squiggly underline demanding I spell it correctly. I don't understand how this is any different from "cannot" versus "can not."

Comment: @jdstankosky: Very obviously difference. One is widely accepted and used; one is not. Whether you believe in prescriptive or conventional correctness of language, there's a clear-cut reason that "each other" is not acceptable while "cannot" is.

Answer (score 9):

I don't remember seeing this before. If I was given some English text to correct and saw "eachother" I would certainly change it to "each other".

But, looking at the Wiktionary there are quite a few examples:

> 1826, G. H. C. Egestorff (translator),
>   Friedrich Gottlieb Klopstock (author),
>   Klopstock's Messiah (Der Messias),
>   canto XIV, lines 94–6, page 427:
>
> The pilgrims to the heavenly Salem,
>   who / By nature for **eachother** were
>   design’d, / In this life oft are near,
>   yet do not meet.
>
> 1921 April, Charles Johnston,
>   "Tao-Teh-King: An Interpretation of
>   Lao Tse's Book of the Way and of
>   Righteousness", part I (of VIII), in
>   The Theosophical Quarterly, volume
>   XVIII, The Theosophical Society, page
>   347:
>
> Lao Tse is seeking to make clear the
>   relation of the unmanifested and the
>   manifested Logos to **eachother**, as
>   poles of the same Being.

Google books turns up a lot more hits, including the above, which seem to date back a fair way. An interesting one is [this English grammar book](http://books.google.com/books?id=e28PAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT210&dq=%22eachother%22&hl=en&ei=aKODTOKlHIa2vQP_5YSOBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBDgo#v=onepage&q=%22eachother%22&f=false) from 1814.

There are **8,900,000** hits for "eachother" on Google compared to **135,000,000** for "each other".

So it seems to be a kind of minority/historical spelling.

Answer (score 7):

I've never come across "eachother" before, and would dare to claim it isn't ever correct, but more like a spelling mistake.

Or, to put it more "descriptively" (as seems to be customary), "eachother" at least is not standard in any common variety of English. :-)

Some statistical evidence: The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (COCA) finds 10 occurrences of "eachother" (versus 56,000 for "each other"). Also historically it has enjoyed only very sporadic use: [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) (COHA) lists 24 (vs 60,000) occurrences in material from 1810 to 2009. I wouldn't say this qualifies "eachother" as correct.